# UIApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber must be used from main thread only

Tags: swift, notifications, badge

I am using locale badge update, where the badge number is set in NotificationSettings below.  The 'UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber' is read out for the badge number and the Xcode prompted warning 'UIApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber must be used from main thread only' when executed.

### I have two questions:

1. How can I suppress this warning or implement it properly so that the warning does not show?
2. Using locale notification to trigger badge number, the badge number displayed may not be correct if there are cancellation/changes to notification, or the second scheduled notification comes before the first one. Is there a way to set and update badge numbers correctly when triggered locally?

```
            let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            notificationContent.title = "Test Title"
            notificationContent.subtitle = "Test Subtitle"
            notificationContent.body = "Test Body"
            notificationContent.sound = content.sound
// ************* Warning for main thread prompted for this line *************
            notificationContent.badge = NSNumber(value:  UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1)
// **************************************************************************
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
            }
```

Comment: You are reading the value on the background thread and then writing it asynchronously on the main thread:
`notificationContent.badge = NSNumber(value:  UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1)` either you do this operation asynchronously on the main thread (combining it with the mutation you do afterwards) and then wait for its completion in order to get the value and increment it by one, or you do that synchronously when already on the main thread before entering this scope on the background.